# Area under two curves intersect at three points

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, area

The graphs of $y_1 = x^4-2x^2+1$ and $y_2= 1-x^2$ intersect at three points. However, the area between the curves can be found by a single integral. Explain why this is and write an integral for this area.

I found that the second equation squared is the same as the first one and that 2 times the integral from 0 to 1 of $y_2 - y_1 = 4/15$ but I'm not sure if this is what they mean by single integral.

Comment: Could you specify which interval you are considering for your integral? You say you did the calculus for $[0;1]$ but this is not clear at the beginning of your question.

Comment: @Martigan The graphs intersect at $x = -1,0,1$ so the bounds are from $[-1,1]$.

Comment: In that case on that interval, since $y_1=y_2^2$, you know that $y_1 \leq y_2$ on the whole... You don't need to split intervals to do the integral. So your reasoning is OK.

Comment: @Martigan if that is the answer then why would the question ask how the area can be found with a single integral? That's the only way to do these problems anyway.

Comment: No, that's not. If $y_1-y_2$ was changing signs on the interval you wanted to find the area between the curves, you would need to split tthe intervals and compute several integrals, for in reality, the area is $\int |y_1(x)-y_2(x)|dx$, not $\int y_1(x)-y_2(x)dx$

Comment: @Spartan117 See the answer below.

Comment: @Martigan why would it be $\int^1_0 |y_2 - y_1| dx$ or is that also equal to $2\int^1_0 y_2-y_1 dx$ ?

Comment: The area is positive, so you have to take the integrale of the absolute value of the difference. You need to do so on the whole interval you want to consider. In your case, the interval is $[-1;1]$. But given that both of your functions are symmetrical regarding the $y$ axis, you can take the double of the integral on the interval $[0;1]$. This is not linked to the absolute value.

Comment: @Martigan I have it now. Since the top function stays the top function over the interval, you can just integrate it from $[-1,1]$ with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $1-x^2$ on the interval [-1,1] is greater than the first one and the difference of the two functions is an even function. So the area between the curves is 2 times the integral of the difference from 0 to 1. i.e
$A=2\int^1_0{y_2-y_1}$ =$4/15$